# No implicit ordering defined for A in binary tree

Tags: scala, data-structures, binary-tree, generic-programming

I am trying to develop a binary tree structure in Scala, but i have a error that say:

```
 Error:(15, 54) No implicit Ordering defined for A.

 override def add[A](new_value: A): BinaryTree[A] = new Node(NullNode,new_value,NullNode)
```

Can any one explain me how i can fix it? Here is the code, the problem is in the **add** method of the **NullNode** object, this method is called when you try to create a left for a **Node**.

```
sealed abstract class BinaryTree[+A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def isValid: Boolean
  def add[B >: A](new_value: B): BinaryTree[A]
  def isLeaf: Boolean
  def length: Int
}

case object NullNode extends BinaryTree[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  override def isValid: Boolean = true
  override def isLeaf: Boolean = false
  override def add[A](new_value: A): BinaryTree[A] = new Node(NullNode,new_value,NullNode)
  override def length: Int = 0
}

case class Node[A] (
      var left  : BinaryTree[A],
      var value : A,
      var rigth : BinaryTree[A] )
    ( implicit ord: Ordering[A] ) extends BinaryTree[A] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  override def isValid: Boolean = {
    import ord._

    def isValidWith (f: A => Boolean, t: BinaryTree[A]): Boolean = t match {
      case NullNode => true
      case Node(_,valueNode,_) => f(valueNode) && t.isValid
    }

    isValidWith(value < _, left) && isValidWith(value > _, rigth)
  }

  override def isLeaf: Boolean = left.isEmpty && rigth.isEmpty
  override def add[B >: A](new_value: B): BinaryTree[A] = {
    import ord._

    def travel (t: BinaryTree[A]): BinaryTree[A] = t match {
      case NullNode => t.add(new_value)
      case Node (left,nodeValor,rigth) => {
        if (new_value > nodeValor) new Node(travel(left),nodeValor,rigth)
        else if (new_value < nodeValor) new Node(left,nodeValor, travel(rigth))
        else throw new Exception("Valor ya introducido")
      }
    }

    travel(this)
  }
  override def length: Int = {
    def travel (t: BinaryTree[A]): Int = t match {
      case NullNode => t.length
      case Node(left,_,rigth) => left.length + rigth.length + 1
    }

    travel(this)
  }

}

object BinaryTree {
  def apply[A] (value: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): BinaryTree[A] = new Node(NullNode,value,NullNode)
}
```

For the moment, I have tried different implementations, adding **Ordering** to the generic type of the **abstract class** or making the **abstract class** a **trait**, but none of that has worked as I would like. I would be very grateful if someone could explain why this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem comes from the fact that there is no `Ordering[Nothing]` which means `NullNode` can't be ordered, but the `Node.value` type needs to be.

I got it to compile by adding `Ordering` to every `add()` method reference and adjusting the relationship between the `value` type with the `left`/`right` node types.

```
sealed abstract class BinaryTree[+A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def isValid: Boolean
  def add[B >: A :Ordering](new_value: B): BinaryTree[B]
  . . .
```

. . .

```
case object NullNode extends BinaryTree[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  override def isValid: Boolean = true
  override def isLeaf: Boolean = false
  override def add[A:Ordering](new_value: A): BinaryTree[A] =
    Node(NullNode, new_value, NullNode)
  . . .
```

. . .

```
case class Node[A,C<:A](left  : BinaryTree[C]
                       ,value : A
                       ,rigth : BinaryTree[C]
                       )(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) extends BinaryTree[A] { . . .
```

. . .

```
override def add[B >: A :Ordering](new_value: B): BinaryTree[B] = {
  import ord._

  def travel(t: BinaryTree[A]): BinaryTree[B] = t match { . . .
```

There are other issues and problems with the code, but at least this compiles.

Comment: thank you, with your proposal I have fixed the problems and please if you have any suggestions to improve, tell me, this was just a small test to learn how to use scala